# Command parameters for b2 in order to build Boost libraries with Microsoft's Clang/C2

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, clang

I have been trying to compile Boost libraries using b2 in Windows but using Clang/C2 (Clang 3.7 with Microsoft CodeGen), to no success. Since Visual Studio comes with several toolsets to use at build time, it seems it shouldn't be too hard to specify which. I have seen another posting relating to "building boost with clang 3.8 on windows" but his proposal to use as command line for b2 is in error because it is not really invoking the clang compiler from MSVC. The person posting that used the following command line:

```
b2 --build-dir=build toolset=clang --build-type=complete stage
```

I am a stranger to b2 and the Boost.Build tools... all I want is to use Boost from MSVC with Clang/C2 instead of the default compiler.

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated..

Juan Dent

BTW: I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

Comment: What makes you think that this is a supported build path by Boost?

Comment: Well, clang is a major cross platform compiler and its availability in VStudio appears to suggest that Microsoft wants to offer support for this compiler. I would actually ask why wouldn't it be supported?

Comment: Because Clang/C2 is *new*; it's less than 6 months old. Support for things like that does not magically appear. According to the [release notes for the 1.61 release](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_61_0.html), they don't even test on Clang/C2.

Comment: I understand...I wonder how long will it take to become an option in Boost... Thank you @NicolBolas!

Answer (score 0):

`boost` supports `clang` on `mac os x` so it should build it on `windows` and `linux`.

On `windows` `boost` builds for `visual studio` by default. When building for `mingw` I run `bootstrap.bat mingw` before `b2`. So to build for `clang` on `windows`, ensure that `clang` is in the `PATH` and try:

```
cd boost_1_xx_0
bootstrap.bat clang

b2 -j8 toolset=clang address-model=64 architecture=x86 --build-dir=build --build-type=complete stage
```

Comment: 'clang++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.  This is the error message upon execution of your command line

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that it didn't work. Apparently `boost` does not support `clang` on `windows` yet, see [clang++ on windows support](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5943) for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

To build with Visual Studio's clang (clang-cl), use `toolset=clang-win`. I came across this question while searching for the same info, and gleaned the answer from [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62445912/6115748). Tested with Visual Studio 2022.