# How to use boost asio with clang/c2

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, build, clang

**TL;DR**:

- Has anyone been able to use boost asio (boost version is 1.61) with clang/c2 (the clang++ frontend that is integrated into VS2015 Update 3)?
- If yes, what options did you use?

---

I have a program that uses boost's asio library. It works flawlessly when compiled with MSVC++ (VS2015 Update 3) on Win10 and g++4.8 on Ubuntu 14.04, but I'd also like to use the clang frontend that is shipped with newer versions of Visual Studio (I believe since update 1).

My initial command line options (copied from the project properties page) looked like this:

> -fpic "stdafx.h" -std=c++1y -fstack-protector "Clang\" -fno-strict-aliasing -ffunction-sections -g2 -gdwarf-2 -O0 -x c++-header -D "_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS" -D "NOMINMAX" -frtti -fomit-frame-pointer -fdata-sections -fno-ms-compatibility -std=c11 -fexceptions -o "Clang\%(filename).obj" -fms-extensions -fno-short-enums

Which gave me the following error:

```
void __cdecl boost::detail::atomic_increment(struct __clang::_Atomic<int> *)': Unexpected atomic instruction -- use Windows interlock intrinsics
```

So apparently boost tired to use clang/gcc intrinsics that are not supported by the clang/c2 version instead of using the windows specific intrinsics it would use when compiled with VC++. I played around with the different compiler options and the only thing that seemed to have any effect was to un-define the `__clang__` preprocessor symbol (adding the following option to the command line):

```
-U "__clang__"
```

That got rid of the atomic error, but now I get multiple pages of error messages that seem to be related to some boost mpl macros. Here are the first few lines:

```
1>  In file included from main.cpp:1:
1>  In file included from D:\mylibs\boost\include\boost/program_options.hpp:15:
1>  In file included from D:\mylibs\boost\include\boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:13:
1>  In file included from D:\mylibs\boost\include\boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:12:
1>  In file included from D:\mylibs\boost\include\boost/any.hpp:20:
1>  In file included from D:\mylibs\boost\include\boost/type_index.hpp:29:
1>  In file included from D:\mylibs\boost\include\boost/type_index/stl_type_index.hpp:40:
1>D:\mylibs\boost\include\boost/mpl/if.hpp(131,23): error : too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
1>  BOOST_MPL_AUX_NA_SPEC(3, if_)
1>                        ^
1>  D:\mylibs\boost\include\boost/preprocessor/facilities/expand.hpp(26,10) :  note: macro 'BOOST_PP_EXPAND_I' defined here
1>  # define BOOST_PP_EXPAND_I(x) x
1>           ^
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Note that my question is not about building the boost libraries themselves as in this post: [Command parameters for b2 in order to build Boost libraries with Microsoft's Clang/C2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153049/command-parameters-for-b2-in-order-to-build-boost-libraries-with-microsofts-cla). And yes, I'm aware that there is no official support for clang/c2 from boost, but I was wondering if someone knows a hack that would produce the correct set of boost configuration macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting **Boost** headers to compile cleanly with **Clang/C2** is critical to making **Clang/C2** useful, so we're working on support for the `Clang-style` atomic intrinsics. They'll be available in a future update of **Clang/C2**.

I'm not aware of a way to convince **Boost** to use the **MSVC** version of the intrinsics while still compiling with **Clang**, unless you're willing to hack the Boost headers.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. For testing purposes, I would actually be willing to hack the headers if someone could tell me exactly where I have to change what. Right now it is just not important enough for me to dig through the boost configuration headers myself searching for the correct defines if I don't know, if it is even possible at all in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the macro `BOOST_SP_USE_STD_ATOMIC` in your compiler options or immediately before you `#include` any Boost headers.